# How do you clip gridlines so that they don't appear over continents with cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'd like to create a map using cartopy that draws gridlines that are clipped by the continents so that they only appear over the ocean and not over land. Whether they're actually clipped or whether I just control the drawing order so that my data is drawn over them is not important to me; either way would work.

I'm in Python 3, using cartopy 0.17 and matplotlib 3.1.1.

```py
from cartopy.crs import PlateCarree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 1), projection=PlateCarree())

ax.gridlines()
ax.coastlines()
```

I've tried calling `gridlines` before and `coastlines` and vice versa but either way the gridlines end up being drawn over the continents, so clearly the order in which these things are drawn is determined in a different way.

I've also tried this plotting some data using `ax.contourf` and I get the same thing: the gridlines appear over the opaque colors created by the data. So it's not just the fact that `coastlines` only draws an outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the result you want?

```py
from cartopy.crs import PlateCarree
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 1), projection=PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='white', zorder=1)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.gridlines(zorder=0)
```